# Do you "follow" a process, or "use" a process?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I am writing instructions for a global company that is implementing a new management process. Should I tell employees to "use" the new process? Or is it correct to say "follow" the new process?

Which one is 'more' correct or common?

Comment: Why would employees *use* a management process? They're the ones being processed, going through it. The managers implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say *use* is wrong, but using less generic words is always a plus, especially in business writing.  *Use* has so many uses, that it doesn't convey any extra information.  You may argue that *follow* is redundant with *process* as they kind of go hand in hand, but that's pretty much how language works.  It's more understandable this way because the reader gets a few hints along the way about what you are trying to convey.

Answer (score 0):

[Per Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=used+the+process%2Cfollowed+the+process&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), neither is much more common than the other.  [In AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=used+the+process%2Cfollowed+the+process&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3), "used" is somewhat more common; [in BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=used+the+process%2Cfollowed+the+process&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) they are used about equally.